# How do you discriminate tagged unions when narrowing types using a type guard?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, union-types, discriminated-union

Consider a helper function

```js
const isKeyOf = <K extends PropertyKey, O extends object>(key: K, object: O): key is K & keyof O => key in object
```

Here, `isKeyOf` narrows the key type when checking if a key exists in an object

```js
const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}

const key: string = "a" // type of key is string

if (isKeyOf(key, obj)) {
    // type of key is "a" | "b" | "c"
}
```

This works fine as long as obj is not a union of types, however:

```js
const holder: Record<number, { a: number } | { b: number }> = {
    1: { a: 1 },
    2: { b: 2 }
}

// type of obj is { a: number } | { b: number }
const obj = holder[1 as number]
const key: string = "a" // type of key is string
 
if (isKeyOf(key, obj)) {
     // type of key is never!
     // However, this branch does execute, and
     console.log(typeof key) // prints string
     console.log(obj) // prints { a: 1 }
}
```

After some investigation, I figured this is because the `keyof` operator only lists keys that are common to all types in a union

```
type objType = { a: number } | { b: number }
type key = keyof objType // = never
```

yet, in this case I've checked that `key` is indeed `in objType` in the type guard. How do I write a type guard that correctly checks this and assigns the correct type to key?

Comment: You can use an `extends any` over the union of object to distribute the operation and then check to see if the key extends keyof the object.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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) work for you?

Comment: @wonderflame that seems to work! Could you write an answer detailing how the (O extends O ? keyof O : never) works? Thanks!

Comment: sure, already on it

Comment: Is there a way to simultaneously narrow the union type such that `obj[key]` is possible? Because if `key` is `"a" | "b"` it can't safely access `obj`

Comment: @Lumin I'm not sure if I understood the case correctly. Could you add some test case in playground?

Comment: I've added a playground link in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254949/discussion-between-lumin-and-wonderflame).

Comment: @Lumin responded in the chat

Comment: @wonderflame responded

Comment: I'm going to ask a separate question to keep the discussion on topic for this question

Comment: sure, just ping me

Comment: @wonderflame https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76924339/how-do-i-safely-access-an-object-that-has-a-union-type-with-a-non-literal-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the `keyof` operator will return only the common keys, thus the following type will result in `never`:

```
// never
type Result = keyof ({ a: string } | { b: string });
```

To fix it we need to check `keyof` for every member of the *union* separately. So our end result should look like this:

```
// "a" | "b"
type Result = keyof { a: string } | keyof { b: string };
```

We can achieve this by using [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). *Union* types are distributed whenever they are checked against some condition using `extends`. Example:

```
type Test<T> = T extends number ? T : never;

// 1
type Result = Test<'a' | false | [] | 1>
```

To make sure that we don't lose any members like in the previous example, we need to have a condition that will be always true. Possible conditions are to check against `any` or the `T` itself, since `T extends T` is always true:

```
type Test<T> = T extends T ?  keyof T : never;

// "a" | "b"
type Result = Test<{ a: string } | { b: string }>
```

Looks good! Let's adapt it to your *type guard*:

```
const isKeyOf = <K extends PropertyKey, O extends object>(
  key: K,
  object: O,
): key is K & (O extends O ? keyof O : never) => key in object;
```

Testing:

```
const obj = holder[1 as number];
const key: string = 'a'; // type of key is string

if (isKeyOf(key, obj)) {
  key; // "a" | "b"
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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)