# How do I safely access an object that has a union type with a non-literal key?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, union-types, discriminated-union

Given an object:

```js
const obj = { a: 1 } as { a: number } | { b: number }
const key = "a" as string

if (key in obj) {
  console.log(obj[key])
  // string cannot be used to index { a: number } | { b: number }
}
```

How do I safely access `obj` (without type assertion)?

I've can't use literal checks

```js
if ("a" in obj) {
   // obj.a is number
}
```

since the value of `key` is not pre-determined.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvGBDAXDAjDAL7YQbZ5gCuAtvAKYBOxMAPufJbQ80QFChIsANb0AnqhgAiLFNIxojAJZgA5nz5KAZjAAUoiSrhIAlBj4wYgiCAA29AHS2Qq3QkQBtAwF0TFmAD0AQpQympWWGBgILAMMFQQ9AAmMFAgMCpJ9AAe5Lgw1HRMLOyYnAXcxfz8QA)

Comment: Sure, fixed that.

Comment: if both are not pre-determined then what should be the type of the `obj[key]`?

Comment: `number` -- All the keys have the same type for the value

Comment: Well `key` has to be a `keyof obj`, right? Or else that code wouldn't work. So give it that type rather than `string`.

Comment: `keyof typeof obj` is actually `never`: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76924030/how-do-you-discriminate-tagged-unions-when-narrowing-types-using-a-type-guard/76924115#76924115

Comment: Can't know about requirements/restrictions if you don't tell us about them. We're not all following you around keeping notes about your questions...

Comment: @jcalz Your solutions seems to be the best option here and it does work fully

Comment: @jcalz - Why did you delete your first comment, telling the OP to change his key to a constant fixed literal?

Comment: That’s not what I said; I told OP to change `eval` to something else, without changing the types.  I deleted it because my advice was taken so it was no longer relevant. I’m not sure why it matters though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort of [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) you're trying to do with `if (key in obj)` is unfortunately tricky to get right.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#34867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34867) for an official discussion about it.

Currently TypeScript will cannot narrow `key` when you check `key in obj`; this is requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#43284](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284), but that would interact poorly with some of the existing [`in`-operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) that acts on the type of `obj`.

Even if key narrowing were implemented, it wouldn't work very well when `obj` is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  In some sense you're trying to narrow both `key` and `obj` at once, in some sort of correlated way, such that `key in obj` implies that the pair `[key, obj]` is of a type like `["a", {a: number}] | ["b", {b: number}]`.

But there is no facility in TypeScript to handle such things; see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for the general problem with correlated unions; often these can be refactored to use generics instead, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), but in this case it wouldn't be even remotely worth the effort.

---

Probably my recommendation here is that you should *widen* the type of `obj` to something more amenable to indexing with an unknown key.  Perhaps with an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) like

```
const _obj: { [k: string]: number | undefined } = obj;
```

This represents the idea that any property will either be `number` or missing/`undefined`, and you can just index directly (without `in` checking) and compare against `undefined`:

```
const val = _obj[key];
if (typeof val !== "undefined") {
    console.log(val)
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.1.6#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAXDA3jAhqsBXAtvAKYBOMAvjAD7ozw4HFmUC8AUDJzALKZQAWAOhKYwAExD4AFAEoYAHhgAGQQFYYAflrYYARgoxUGejABMFANxsANkVgBrIgE8YLGACJM7q21CRYAPoIKLQA2vao0CQAlmAA5gC6DISk1DC44kQAZrFEYgZuwVZ+0DAAbpjWrjBBSOHOCVbRWTBSUE4ADkQgLRVVAIQsbu4ZYtm5Yu5yaBxcJSC2gtYgcVJ9MmzkbEA)

Answer (score 0):

A fun way to do it is

```
function isKeyOf<ObjT extends (Record<string,any>)>(k: string | number | symbol, obj: ObjT): k is keyof ObjT {
    return k in obj;
}

declare const obj: { a?: number, b?: number };
declare const key: string;


if (isKeyOf(key,obj)) {
  console.log(obj[key])
}
```

but if you are in a hurry you can also do

```
declare const obj: { a?: number , b?: number };
declare const key: string;

if (key in obj) {
  console.log(obj[key as keyof typeof obj])
}
```

Note1: I took the liberty of changing `{a:number}|{b:number}` to `{a?:number,b?:number}` because the way that TypeScript evaluates `{a:number}|{b:number}` to a `never` type, which is probably not what you intended.

Note2: I also used `declare const` forms, rather than explicit constant values, so that it is clear that the key needs to be type verified before being used to access the object. (Otherwise the question is trivial).

### Update

```
function isKeyOf<ObjT extends (Record<string,any>)>(k: string | number | symbol, obj: ObjT): k is keyof ObjT {
    return k in obj;
}
const obj = (Math.random()<0.5) ? { a: 1 } : { b: 2 }; 
declare const key: string;
if (isKeyOf(key,obj)) {
  console.log(obj[key])
}
```

In this version the TypeScript infers the type of `obj` to be `{a: number;b?: undefined;}|{b: number;a?: undefined;}`, which is reduces to `{a?: number;b?: undefined;}`.  It is only in this special one-line conditional form that TypeScript will generate a non-never union of types with no common keys.  So generally, if you want a conceptual "union" of types with disparate keys you can do something like

```
type AB = Partial<{a:number} & {b: number}>
//{
//    a?: number | undefined;
//    b?: number | undefined;
//}
```

But the keys are are all optional - that's a limitation.

Comment: The problem is that `key` is `never` and that's what OP wanted to avoid in his previous question

Comment: @wonderflame updated to use a non-never object type - the never type was probably unintentional.  The non-never type still has the compiler error, and this answer faddreses that.

Comment: @jcalz updated to a non never type

Comment: @CraigHicks OP: `How do I safely access obj (without type assertion)?`. So your solution isn't covering that case

Comment: So the original form of the the question used eval, which I have replcated using declare const.  The question should have been modified to remove `without type assertion` instead.

Comment: Changed to `{a?: number, b?: number}`.  As you know, TypeScript has  limitations about union types - it interprets union as the intersection of keys.  If your typescript link, if you remove the type and use `const obj = Math.random() < 0.5 ? { a: 1 } : { b: 2 };` instead, the inferred type is effectively `{a?: number, b?: number}`.  But that only works with one-liners, otherwise the union becomes never.  So "no", I don't think it is a different question than the originally posted question.  The question as edited uses a literal "a" instead of string, but that's a really trivial question.

Comment: @jcalz - oops, forgot to put your name in the reply.

Comment: @wonderflame - The question still says "the value of key is not pre-determined", ever though it is now been edited to be literal "a" instead, rendering the question self-contradictory.